# Silverlight4 net.tcp binding

Tags: wcf, silverlight-4.0

Hi
I have a SL4 application which uses a WCF service  using net.tcp binding. If i remove http from the protocols of the service in IIS (Advanced settings ) and keep only net.tcp , the service fails with an error saying that the service could not be activated. 
Does http need to be added to the proptocols of the service in IIS for the net.tcp to work?
i cannot enable http on IIS  for the service protocols.
are there any workarounds

thanks
Ben

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue resolved. was something very small that i had overlooked. 
The mexhttp binding was present and the
httpGetEnabled was set in the service behaviors
removing the above resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

Which version of IIS are you using? Net.TCP will fail if you are not using IIS7 or when a butterfly flaps its wings in Tokyo.

Have you seen this blog post?

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/WCF-NET.TCP-Protocol-in-Silverlight-4.aspx

Comment: i am using IIS7. i have gone through the post but i wanted to enable only the net.tcp protocol and not http for the service hosted in IIS

Comment: What do your bindings look like?

Comment: binding is net.tcp port 4502, protocol enabled on in IIS7 are http,net.tcp for the site.